# How should I flag an answer that CLEARLY doesn't even remotely relate to the question?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

Some time I ago, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033738/does-petersons-algorithm-satisfy-starvation/23586815#23586815): (deleted answer)

> ### Heading
>
> Blockquote   This will be displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces
>       will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved.
>
> ```
> Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
> ```

No, the question ("Does Peterson's algorithm satisfy starvation?") had nothing to do with markdown.

(And worse yet, someone upvoted this answer...)

How should I flag this?

My first thought is "Spam", as this user clearly didn't even bother to read the question at all (which should be obvious, even to a "janitor"), and should be treated similar to a spammer. But then again, it isn't "an advertisement", as the reason dictates.

"Not an Answer" I guess makes sense, but should we really be treating this user the same as a new user who isn't too familiar with the guidelines? Shouldn't we get rid of this user ASAP?

Comment: A genuinely legitimate use of the "Not an Answer" flag.  As usual, if there's any doubt, just cast a custom flag and explain the problem.  It's not spam.  VLQ works too.  Actually, any flag except the Spam flag would work here.

Comment: Not enough information to answer that imho. Could that "answer" be marginally construed to answer a question, even if it is a horrible answer then? In that case, I would avoid NAA. SPAM is just not right anyway, and too big a hammer to risk misuse.

Comment: On SE sites, "spam" means something more specific that it does it common parlance: the flag for it describes it as "*advertisement* with no disclosure" If a user posts 100 answers that are "asdfasdf" (or something like in the question here) the fact that there are 100 of them does not make them "spam" because it is not advertising anything. (Even though a lot of us would call these 100 messages "spam".) So "spam" is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Deduplicator I found the link and edited the question to include it.

Comment: This looks like an experiment with Markdown. The formatting sandbox should be used for that.

Comment: Curiously, I've found identical text on [an answer today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620098/3025856). I'm not sure what the source is, but assume it's some tutorial on how to format markdown. If you search Stack Overflow, there appear to be a few cases of people posting this text as answers. Anyway, I've flagged it as _NAA_ per the instructions below, so we'll see if it gets picked up by the review queue.

Answer (score 31):

That's the very definition of "Very Low Quality", isn't it?

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

I mean, how could that be edited into anything even remotely useful?

Answer (score 17):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586815) you were referring to there are a few options:

1. Flag as Not An Answer - this definitely wasn't an answer to the question or any question
2. Flag using a Custom "Other" flag - explain what seems suspicious about the answer including that is isn't an answer and it has unusual upvotes for such a low-quality answer.

Keep in mind, the Not An Answer flags funnel into the Low Quality review queue so it could get deleted without a moderator seeing that post.  If you think that this needs moderator attention, then use the "Other" flag so we could step in and destroy/delete the user if needed.

Comment: If it looks like an answer to the question or to a question? Because somewhere not long ago, I saw a post/comment by mods implying NAA should be resolvable without looking at the question...

Comment: It's hard to imagine how the example text could be construed as anything but an unfinished non-answer.

Comment: I do sometimes destroy these accounts, because these random formatting tests and "asfksfkj" gibberish are often the precursor for a spam campaign. I think they're testing the limits of what the system accepts so that they can see how to hide their spam. I've accepted spam flags before on posts like this for that reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator To a question, when we review the flags we are typically seeing the answer in its own context without the question.

Comment: @BradLarson Agreed but it is difficult to say without more context.

Comment: Eh, I *always* destroy users who post gibberish. No reason to keep them around.

Comment: @BoltClock but surely it depends on the type of crap. :)

Comment: In light of answers to this question can I ask why flagging [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554649/listbox-display-manipulation-highlight-first-3-itemsnot-selected-row/22554900#22554900) answer as very low quality has been disputed? Not only it is link only answer but also points to WinForm answer for WPF question

Comment: @dkozl  That flag went into the Low Quality Review queue and the community voted that it looked good so it wasn't removed.  I'd suggest you post a different question if you need more details about that specific answer.