# How is an Answer defined?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, not-an-answer

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436463/how-do-i-declare-an-array-as-a-constant-in-objective-c) the OP asked how to create constant objects in Objective-C.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307133/106435) does not even try to answer it but hints out some unrelated code issues — something I would use a comment for. Therefore I think it should be transformed to an comment. Or aren't comment the appropriate tool for that?
So I flagged the answer (actually three times) but the response says: it looks like an answer, it is an answer.
In my second flagging I said: "if we look on the question, this is not an answer." It was declined with:

> "the definition of "not an answer" is that you must not look at the question in order to determine if it is an answer - this very clearly fits the definition of an answer"

I find that quite ridiculous, as it doesn't even fit to the title of the question.

So if it doesn't contain a question mark it is an answer?
If it contains a rhetorical question, it isn't an answer?

and for questions:
If the title doesn't contain *how*, *what*, *why* or *wtf* should I close it as not a valid question (would fit to more than 80% of the questions)

So if next time someone asks about date time calculation my answer won't be deleted, although it reads "Yes, the number of dwarfs is 7!" (<- looks like an answer, this very clearly fits the definition of an answer)

**Can an answer be an answer without the context of the question? How do we define an answer?**

Comment: Work with the questioner and downvote the bad answer?

Comment: @dilbert: of yours I down voted it. but that is not the question. my question: can a answer be an answer with out the context of the question?

Comment: of course not. A question is what distinguishes an answer from a statement. As in, `1 + 1 = 2` instead of just `2`. Context is everything.

Comment: Somewhat related - [How should I flag an answer that CLEARLY doesn't even remotely relate to the question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254558)

Comment: The very idea of an answer doesn't make sense without the context of its question.

Comment: wrong answers are still answers, they are just bad answers. Bad answers should be down voted, not flagged.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This isn't about the definition of an answer, it's about what kind of information you need to convey when flagging something.

A "not an answer" flag only tells moderators and reviewers one thing: this answer should be unilaterally deleted. That has to clear a pretty high bar to begin with, because people get very angry when you delete their content without a good reason. When moderators review these flags in our flag queue, all we see is the answer, nothing else. In addition, "not an answer" flags are increasingly being handled by the community via the Low Quality Posts review queue. <strike>Again, all the community members see are the flagged posts, nothing more.</strike> Reviewers there do see the question below the post, but let's just say that many reviewers are not as thorough as moderators are, and may not read that far down.

For one of these flags, it should be obvious on its face why the post should be deleted: it's gibberish, a question being asked in an answer, a "me too" response, spam, or trolling. If it's not, the burden falls on the flagger to provide that context and explain why this answer should be deleted.

Even your second flag in this case: "if we look on the question, this is not an answer" doesn't really help us out that much. You're requiring the moderator who reads this to be a subject matter expert and to parse the question before trying to puzzle out how this answer is not really an answer. Again, if it's not obvious to us, our default is to not delete something someone else has posted (leaning even more towards that if the post was upvoted, as it was here).

Your third flag finally provided the information we needed: "This should be a comment. it does not address the question but just describes an typo within the question's text." Now we know what it is that you saw here. (You might have also pointed out that this typo was corrected in the question three years ago, making the answer obsolete in any case.) At that point we can feel comfortable deleting the answer.

The generic "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags should be for items whose removal is obvious, particularly now that average community members will be voting on the deletion of these posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue. If it isn't, please help us out by providing the context that we might otherwise miss. A little help on the flagger's part can save us a lot of time and consternation.

Comment: "all the community members see are the flagged posts, nothing more" - we see the question below the answer.

Comment: @Dukeling - Has that always been that way? It's been a long time since I used review, but I recall that extra context not being there.

Comment: I don't know if the tools moderators use, do provide it or not. That s why I said in my answer that tools should reflect the fact that answers are nothing in the context of the question. Also normal users do not now how much information they should provide, again as they aren't aware of what moderators are aware. But as always +1 for a great and thoughtful explanation.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - The difficulty with requiring a moderator to need to read the question in order to understand why an answer doesn't address it properly is that this often requires subject matter expertise. Moderators can't possibly have a broad enough skill set to handle all the various languages and frameworks covered by this site. Likewise, reviewers will come from all different areas and may not see the thing that you did. The more content someone has to read to understand why something should be deleted, the greater the chance they'll miss what you saw.

Comment: @BradLarson, I am aware of that. But I don't know if usually a Objective-C veteran will review flags on it's tag. Also I don't know if the moderator is ware that 27 users voted on the comment "should be a comment". I did assume both. But it isn't about this very single flag. i have 1628 helpful flags. only few disputed or declined. I think I know how to flag. it was just this explanation with the definition of answers that confused me.

Comment: Regardless of who sees it or what they see, @vikingosegundo, the important bit of information here is that the answer was superfluous - regardless of what value it might have once held, it no longer offered anything of value to anyone because the correction had been made to the post long ago. Simply writing that would've resolved the situation much more easily.

Comment: I just want to raise the awareness that the offered tools are maybe not designed clear enough. They are not giving any hint of what information must be included and what moderators see anyway. personally I think if I had seen the explanation of my second flag I'd just opened another tab in my browser and read the question. and If I had come to the conclusion that I am not able to judge it, I had seen that 28 people had given their impression that it should be a comment. and if I still would had been insecure I'd had left it for another more competent moderator to decide.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I am considering writing up a collective Q&A with guidance on how to use flags (especially mod flags) most effectively. Still debating whether it'd be helpful to a significant number of users, or if we should just stick with decline messages instead.

Comment: @BoltClock whatever guidance you're going to make, it would better take into account that vast majority of VLQ/NAA flaggers and reviewers [will never see it](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584/168 "'Review in this queue is supposed to run without any meta guidance. This is a matter of simple math...'")

Comment: @gnat: Of course. If people don't care to learn, I'm not going to care about those people. For those who *do* care, I will indulge them greatly.

Comment: @BoltClock FWIW, we're talking about like 30,000 users (LQ queue reviewers), vast majority of these won't ever have a chance to notice whether you or me or whoever cares or not

Comment: @BradLarson To quote the flag itself, `It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.`  It does **not** mean "this answer should be unilaterally deleted."

Answer (score 5):

I want to share my own opinion:

Stack Overflow is a Knowledge Database in *Question&Answer* style — not *some questions, some unrelated answers* style.
There should be no definition separating what makes an answer from it's question.
An good answer to the wrong question is one thing: useless.

In my example the answerer might have been a valid point: he showed OP an issue, but he didn't even try to address the real question. OP was grateful and fixed his question's code. The answer, that never was one, is complete obsolete now.

The review and moderation tools and the high reputation users and moderators mindset should reflect one simple truth: Questions and answers belong together. A purely syntactical analysis of answers won't lead to good answers or higher over all quality.

Comment: If you feel that an answer is not useful you have a tool *specifically* designed for you to provide that feedback, a downvote.  Downvotes are *specifically* designed to indicate that you find an answer not useful.  An answer being the wrong answer to a question is not grounds for moderator deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the number of dwarfs is 7!

Comment: @vikingosegundo, this is an answer, its just a very bad one. I would downvote it but, I'm not allowed.