# Moderator declined an NAA flag, and the answer is an improvement on other answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690947/how-can-i-access-cookie-from-internetexplorer-application/46869652#46869652) NAA, since it's a comment clarifying how to change the accepted answer to work with 64-bits Microsoft Office. The answer even starts with *For the accepted answer to work on 64-bit Excel*.

The answer included *Wanted this to be a comment, not enough rep.* in his initial answer, but that got removed by an editor.

Since I realized it looked somewhat like an answer, I threw in a comment too, clarifying why this was not an answer, to make the job easier for reviewers and moderators.

However, the flag still got declined by a moderator (not by the queue).

Is this really an answer? Is there something more I could've done to appropriately handle this?

A quick summary of the post:

---

**Question:** How do I get cookies from a page using the InternetExplorer.Application object

**Answer 1:**

External function declaration to sleep the current process (32 bits only)

Segment of code to open up Internet Explorer, load a page, use that external function declaration to sleep until the page has loaded, then get the cookies after the page has finished loading

**Answer 2:** (NAA imo)

Adaptation to make the external function declaration 64-bits compatible.

---

Since answer 2 is fully unrelated to the question, or the goal of the question, and only addresses a minor change to make answer 1 more broadly applicable, this is clearly not an answer in my opinion.

---

The answer on the question this question has been marked a duplicate of, states *You flag things posted as answers that do not attempt to answer the question*. By that rule, I've flagged the answer, since the answer doesn't attempt to address the question, it instead addresses an issue raised in the comments of the first answer, that the answer is not compatible with 64-bit programs.

<sub>I considered incorporating the note this answer gives into the accepted answer, but that does break compatibility with VBA 6 (Microsoft Office 2007 and earlier), and to fix that would require a little more code, and then I'd likely have to add an explanation for every part of the answer since the code would become even less self-explanatory. It's best converted to a comment on the accepted answer in my opinion.</sub>

Comment: The only question we should be asking ourself is "can this answer stand on its own and fully solve the issue presented in the question?". If I read your post correctly, your assessment to that question is "no".

Comment: @Braiam Indeed, the first answer declares an external DLL function to be able to sleep, opens up internet explorer, loads an URL, sleeps while the page hasn't fully loaded, then gets the cookies. The second answer clarifies that the declaration of that external function needs to be changed to be 64-bit compatible, but doesn't address the question (how to get cookies) at all.

Comment: That's not "NAA". It is an attempt at answering the question. It may not be _the_ answer, it may not even answer that question, but that doesn't make it "NAA". "NAA" is for gibberish, _"Me too"_ and other not-even-close to an answer posts like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus How is it an attempt at answering? It's 100% unrelated to the question (how to get cookies from the Internet Explorer application). It fixes an incompatibility with 64-bits Excel for the accepted answer to work, but otherwise has nothing to do with the question or any code shared in the question

Comment: _It may not be the answer, it may not even answer that question, but that doesn't make it "NAA"._

Comment: @Cerbrus could you elaborate? If we deleted all other answers and left that as the only answer in its current form, would readers be capable of solving the issue presented on the question?

Comment: @Cerbrus [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam: Next time, please ask for clarification before simply removing the duplicate.

Comment: @Braiam: That's what the dupe target said. That citation you need [is in the dupe target you removed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1835379)

Comment: @Cerbrus Please explain how the duplicate addresses the specific issue. I've read it, and still believe this is NAA. If that other answer would get deleted, this answer would be nothing at all, just an empty note how to declare a function unrelated to the code shared in the question

Comment: @Cerbrus [**authoritative** citation needed] Just because someone decided to write that in a post, doesn't mean its true, specially if it **contradicts the help center** "Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be ***removed***" The help center establish that it's fair game to get such answers deleted. We cannot contradict the help center.

Comment: @Braiam: That answer was primarily written by [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters).

Comment: @Cerbrus and Martijn Pieters is still bound to the help center. That's *argumentum ad autoritarium* and the only thing it does is demonstrate that you don't have a solid argument.

Comment: I see you have a "history" on that answer, going as far as trying to rolling back Martijn's rollbacks of your edits. I don't think we're going to agree here. I say that that's how it's been done for a long time. There are moderators that back up that process. The help center ___doesn't___ say you need to use the ___NAA flag___ to have the answer removed.

Comment: @Cerbrus of course I'm not going to agree because Martinj is in clear opposition of the help center. He is imposing its own views over what Stack Exchange, the owners of the site and the only *real authority* that can decides what kind of content gets posted on it, established as good.

Comment: @Braiam: He's in opposition of ___your interpretation___ of the help center. You're advocating for the use of the NAA flag, while the help center doesn't tell you to use that flag. It has ben standard practice for ages not to use NAA for these kinds of answers.

Comment: This discussion will be had many a times and will continue to be had due to the literal meaning of NAA. The NAA flag does not mean 'this answer does not answer the question' in the sense that it is not a valid answer, it means that 'this answer is not an answer because it a comment or it is asking for clarification, it is anything but an answer'. I, myself have been stumped by this many times but if you take NAA with what I mentioned above then the rejection of your flag may make more sense. I would advocate to the change of the name of the flag, but I'm not sure what too.

Comment: @Script47 I know about that, the point is: this one is a comment. It's a good comment on how to make the accepted answer work on 64-bit systems, it fixes the issue noted by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690947/how-can-i-access-cookie-from-internetexplorer-application/46869652#comment29260798_9691363). It's __NOT__ an attempt to answer the question, it's an attempt to __IMPROVE ANOTHER ANSWER__. I get what you're all saying, but it's just not applicable to this case.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ah, yes I see what you mean and I understand your sentiments too. I would also (personally) agree that within the context of NAA, that answer isn't an answer as it wouldn't (possibly) exist if a previous answer hadn't been posted. It seems like somewhat of a catch 22.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not advocating the use of the NAA flag. I'm advocating the deletion of these answer for whichever the medium possible. **The moderator should have just deleted the answer** however medium happened to bring that post to its attention.

Comment: @Braiam: That's another discussion. I agree the answer could be bad. NAA just wasn't the right flag.

Comment: Related, but from the opposite perspective: [Why would I make a new answer when all I want to do is supplement an existing one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362632/7795130)

Comment: Also related: [What is the proper flag for an answer that just adds code to another answer (both on the same question)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327441/what-is-the-proper-flag-for-an-answer-that-just-adds-code-to-another-answer-bot)

Comment: @Braiam you're conflating delete votes with flags again

Comment: @TinyGiant you are mistaken. I'm only talking about the result. I don't care about the process.\

Comment: If you don't care about the process, can you not be a persistent cause of confusion and frustration for those that do? @Braiam

Comment: The fact of the matter is that regardless of whether a delete vote would be applicable, NaA is not.

Comment: @TinyGiant My issue in this case is that the moderator should have deleted the answer. It did not. These answers deleted, and if moderators aren't enforcing this, then we have a serious problem.

Comment: @Braiam why should the moderator have deleted the answer? It doesn't seem to be in need of moderator intervention as far as I can tell. The community is perfectly capable of dealing with it with delete votes, and no moderation flags apply... I know that it is frustrating that _you_ can't cast delete votes on answers, and as such there's nothing _you_ can do about it, but that doesn't meant that the _community at large_ can't do something about it, which they can.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this really an answer?

In practice, the NAA flag has been reserved for very obvious non-attempts at answering the question.  In this case, you have to squint pretty hard to discover that this answer may be more appropriate as an edit to the accepted answer it mentions.  NAA flags should not require any specialized domain knowledge to validate.

And honestly, I'm not so sure that this post deserves deletion.  It shouldn't really be a comment because those go away for a whole variety of reasons, and this post contained potentially very helpful information (helpful enough to get an upvote an no downvotes).  Possibly, this is better done as an edit, but even then there's no guarantee that the reviewers/author will approve that for the <2k user.

> Is there something more I could've done to appropriately handle this?

A custom moderator flag *might* help, but it's still a very technical problem, which moderators are often hesitant to act upon.  You can always downvote and delete vote the post if you think it's that bad.  And you can make the edit to the accepted answer to incorporate the details offered in this other post.

Comment: The litmus test for NAA's according to Shog is "strip markdown and still answer the question". How this answer fares with this test?

Comment: Even though it references another answer, it has useful text like "_you must update the "Sleep" definition with the PtrSafe keyword_" and even the __code__ to do so.  That is pretty much what an answer is, code + explanation.  It absolutely passes the at-a-glance litmus test.

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between commentary on another answer with the intent of having the author incorporate the suggested improvement and a derivative work on another answer that provides a *new* answer to the question.  While I think this answer is far less useful as a result of only referencing the answer it is a derived work from, rather than actually including enough portions of that answer to be a useful stand alone answer, I do interpret as a new answer.  That doesn't make it not an attempt to answer the question, but instead an answer that some (including myself) would argue is less useful as a result of being incomplete.

NAA is for things that aren't even trying to answer the question, not for attempts to answer the question that result in answers that you don't think are useful.

Comment: I get your point, but disagree with your assessment of the answer. It's not a derivative work, it's a bug fix for the answer, addressing a bug that's not directly related to the question or the code shared in the question in any way. I still stand by that it didn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No, it's not a bug fix for the answer.  It's a suggested improvement to allow the answer to cover additional versions of the product.  The original answer is perfectly fine when using 32 bit versions of the system, which, given that the original answer appeared to be useful to people, appeared to apply to some portion of the readers.  The additional answer described how you could change it to update it for newer versions of the product.  Mostly products that *didn't even exist at the time the question was originally asked*.

Comment: Ok, _bug fix_ was not the right term, but the underlying point remains, it's not derivative in a way that it holds any solution or attempted solution on its own (and these products certainly did exist back in '12, as noted under the answer the issue occurs with Office 2010)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth How is updating a solution to add new features to it not a derivative work?  Like I said, the answer isn't a *good* answer, because among other things, it doesn't stand alone well, but that doesn't mean it's not an answer, just not a good one.  There are tools for that.  They aren't NAA.  I didn't say that 64 bit systems didn't exist in '12, just that *most* of the versions that now require it have come out since.  It was less common at the time, it's common now.

Comment: It's _one_ keyword added to _one_ line of code. It would be a derivative work if it actually copied the answer and implemented it, and I wouldn't have flagged it as NAA, but imo we shouldn't consider it more than a note or comment. I don't think opening new answers to add a single keyword to an existing answer plus some explanation is appropriate on SO, such things should just be addressed in the comments.

Comment: Also, note that the answerer did include _Wanted this to be a comment, not enough rep._ in the comment, a clear indication that it should be converted to a comment

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth i wholeheartedly agree that any answer that says it's a comment, is a comment and not an answer perfectly matching everyone's definition of NAA in this conversation.

Comment: And as a note to this I would have taken the entire content of the answer and updated it and said "said this is ...'s answer" with a link to the answer and " I have updated his answer to work with 64 bit due to current standard practices of 64 bit."