# Is it right to post a new answer based on another, just because it's missing a direct solution?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031756/access-violation-while-accessing-document-element-in-xmldocument/) and I was surprised that somebody wrote their own answer, which was also accepted, based purely on other answer, just written in code and giving a direct solution to get credit with little-to-no effort.

I think it should be a comment and not a new answer. I have already found a similar case before, but not to such an extent, which I flagged as **not an answer**, and it was rejected. So I wonder if it was right or not. Maybe if I used custom flag, it would have gone through, but I was not sure due to the description.

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another
>   question, or deleted altogether.

When I read it the description again, it actually makes sense. It's related to the question and not to the answers. The fact that it should be a comment on the question as I flagged really makes no sense.

Comment: David is pretty good at guessing at a solution, but he didn't get this one quite right on the first try.  He had to edit his answer to include the solution that Jack recommended.   Typical fastest-gun problem btw.

Comment: On the flagging part, it was not warranted because the answer is still perceived as an attempt to answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1233251

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think so, when you look at the first revision, he wrote there both ways to solve the problem, just without example.

Comment: Highly related (and recent): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376434/moderator-declined-an-naa-flag-and-the-answer-is-an-improvement-on-other-answer

Comment: Hmya, if only we had OPs that do not need examples to understand the solution.  But of course we always do and that's why Jack got the answer mark.  A good answer strategy is to start with a brief "push this button to solve your problem" and elaborate afterwards.  FGITW does not encourage that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] somebody wrote their own answer, which was also accepted, based purely on other answer, just written in code and giving direct solution [...]

So it is not the same answer. There being an explicit solution is a fairly significant difference. That said, given that it would be very straightforward to change the older answer to include the explicit solution, I'd say suggesting that to its author in a comment would be a slightly better way of dealing with the situation, as it might avoid having two answers around where one would suffice. Note that I say "slightly": posting the answer anyway was, at worst, a sub-optimal approach, and not an egregious mistake. Different circumstances -- say, if larger changes were needed to accommodate the explicit solution, or if the other answer had been posted a while before and its author was not around -- could easily shift the balance.

> [...] to get credit with little to no effort.

The second answer does credit the first one (even though it doesn't link to it, which is the optimal way of giving credit to another Stack Overflow post). As for effort, it's neither here nor there: cases of actual plagiarism aside, what matters is what is in the post, not how it was achieved (and, for all we know, the author of the second answer could be perfectly capable of writing an answer as detailed as the first one, had them got there first). The focus should be on making the set of answers to a question as good as possible; anything else is secondary.

> I have already found a similar case before, but not to such an extent, which I flagged as **not an answer**, and it was rejected.

The rejection of that flag was correct. "Not an answer" is for a post that "does not attempt to answer the question", which is clearly not the case here. The answer in discussion here shouldn't be flagged at all. If it were a case of plagiarism -- which, again, it isn't -- a custom mod flag explaining the situation and linking to the other post would be appropriate.

Comment: I guess you're right, at first glance it just doesn't seem right. Take the answer that explains the problem and how to fix it and change it to "write this", because they don't learn anything and this site is supposed to help others in the future and not just OP. I suppose that most people often don't notice other answers and when there is a mention, it is usually to the comment. Including me, I first went through the comments and then I realized he was referring to the next answer.

Comment: Also, one of the reasons for posting another answer is to add detail to an already existing answer. Maybe the second poster didn't come up with the solution, but has a clarification or explanation to add.

Comment: @TheWanderer Yup, that would be a very good reason for posting another answer.