# Should I flag answers that ignore the OP's instructions/preferences in the question?

Tags: discussion, flags

For example, the OP asks for a solution that does **not** involve doing X. Someone provides an answer that is purely based on X. X is not the only solution to the problem, nor is using something other than X "bad practice", so we can safely assume that the answerer did not read the question.

In such situations, should I flag the answer as *Not An Answer* or *Very Low Quality*? The problem is, the answer *does* provide a valid solution. It's just that the OP has explicitly stated they **do not want to solve it that way**.

[This is the question I speak of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23824139), which received a (now deleted) answer that looked like this:

[image: Deleted answer]

This question bears a degree of resemblance to [How should I flag an answer that CLEARLY doesn't even remotely relate to the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254558/), but that one is about answers that are absolutely off-topic.

Comment: Basically if the answer is bad, downvote it, and both flags apply so either is good I'd reckon. However I personally frown upon people asking "How to do Y" and then in the description say "btw without involving X". The title should be something with "Alternatives of doing Y with X" or "How to do Y without X".

Comment: @Jordy The OP did ask correctly though. They're asking how to *add* a control onto the page, not how to show & hide a control on button click. They probably expected someone would offer a show/hide solution, so they mentioned it beforehand. I don't think there's anything wrong with the question (other than being a possible dup & not very well phrased). It's the answerer that I think didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: I agree it was good of him to try to avoid the "quick rep"-answers. But in general (my knowledge of this particular topic is not enough to know if that includes this question) an OP stating he is "open to any other suggestion other than using X" is a red flag and there could be two things going on: (1.) he doesn't want to solve it with X or (2.) it can't be solved with X the way he specified. Option 1: SO doesn't care he doesn't want to use X, if there is an acceptable way to do it without X, somebody will post it as an answer. Or in case of option 2: why bother stating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flagging is not the solution. Downvoting is.

I hate such answers as much as the next guy but the way the system is currently designed, flagging them is not going to lead to the answer being deleted.

The flags are not likely to be successful because when considered **in isolation**, the post is an answer (a bad one for sure, but not "Not An Answer"), that does not suffer from major unintelligibly issues (not "Very Low Quality"). **This is by design.**

Consider this scenario:

- Alice is comfortable with PHP but not with C++ or Java, and flags a PHP answer as NAA.
- Bob is comfortable with C++ but not with PHP or Java, and flags a C++ answer as NAA.
- Carla is comfortable with Java but not with PHP or C++, and flags a Java answer as NAA.

When an NAA or VLQ flag is raised on an answer, they go into the "Low Quality Posts" queue, where other users with the necessary reputation review them.

Assuming that Alice, Bob and Carla flagged according to the current guidelines, this is what happens:

- When Alice runs into Bob's or Carla's flagged answers, she can **readily** make a decision. She does not need to know anything about Java or C++. She also does not need to go look at the question.
- Changing the details that need to be changed, the same scenario happens when Bob or Carla get to the other flagged answers.

Assuming that Alice, Bob and Carla flagged according to guidelines that allow answers that look like actual answers to be flagged as NAA if they do not *actually* answer the question, and that the answers they flagged are those which *look* like answers but to not actually answer their respective questions, this is what happens:

- When Alice runs into Bob's or Carla's flagged answer, she **has** to go look at the question to determine whether the answer is not an answer. **This alone increases the burden of determining whether she agrees with the flag.** Moreover, making this determination requires domain-specific knowledge. If Alice is likely to skip reviewing these answers.
- Changing the details that need to be changed, the same scenario happens when Bob or Carla get to the other flagged answers.

The current system is designed so that people can act on as many review items in the "Low Quality Posts" queue as they can get their hands on, and to make it so that the review can be done quickly.