# How to deal with random use jQuery solutions that do not address the question in need?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

So I was just browsing the JavaScript tag and edited this question:

[How to show hidden div after hitting submit button in form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587326/how-to-show-hidden-div-after-hitting-submit-button-in-form/31587372?noredirect=1#31587407)

Right of the bat `jQuery` solutions popped in, in comments and as answers.

They did nothing to solve the question, and the OP's code actually did work and the problem was totally unrelated to that.

Can we protect question from attracting too much similar answers? How should we proceed? Just downvoting the "unrelated" answers? Ignore them? Flag them as not an answer?

Comment: Downvote, comment, flag where you can, provided those actions can be done for good reason.

Comment: Some might suggest banning jQuery entirely, I couldn't possibly comment as I've already been slapped by the mods recently:)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275258/should-we-recommend-a-jquery-solution-when-javascript-is-equally-short-easily-im , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270437/is-it-fair-to-downvote-answers-that-use-a-certain-library-for-questions-tagged-w , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275208/answering-with-jquery , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251524/how-can-stack-overflow-users-be-encouraged-to-use-jquery-only-when-appropriate , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255881/should-i-flag-answers-that-ignore-the-ops-instructions-preferences-in-the-quest

Comment: I think we should encourage answerers to totally drop that habit and use JQuery

Comment: @Cerbrus You don't flag answers for being wrong, or failing to answer the question.

Comment: @Servy: True, not for being "wrong". But if they're low quality (Which those answers often are)...

Comment: @Cerbrus If the question merits closure for some reason, then yes, it should be closed for that reason.  I don't see how there being an incorrect answer is really related to that at all though.  And regardless, *the answer* shouldn't be flagged just because the question is of low quality.

Comment: Eh, answers, not questions. Whoops, edited my previous comment.

Comment: _Can we protect question from attracting too much similar answers?_ - Protecting questions is a thing but I don't know under which conditions it happens or even if it's automated or not.

Comment: @BSMP: It is automated, if it gets too much low quality answers by new users. I don't know the exact criteria, though.

Comment: JQuery is perhaps a red herring because it is too specific - basically the problem being described here is rather than posting a solution to post an alternative implementation. Right?

Comment: @Cerbrus see [When does Community user protect my question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/839601)

Comment: If the question does not include a framework tag, I usually post a comment along the lines of: [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that the answer isn't useful, say, because it fails to answer the question, then downvote it.  That's exactly what that tool is there for.  If you would like to post a comment explaining why the post isn't useful, you're more than welcome to.